# OData Endpoint doesn't return all properties of the Entity

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, odata-v4

### ASP.NET CORE 2 Web API - OData v4

I have the project which has configuration enabled with the below endpoint & should return the entity - AccountDetails of the Customer

```
https://my.website/odata/accountdetails/{accountNumber}
```

My Project has 2 entities as below,

Entity 1 : **Balancesheet**

```
public class BalanceSheet{
    public int TotalBalance { get; set; }
    public int AvaialableBalance { get; set; }
}
```

Entity 2 : **AccountDetails**

```
public class AccountDetails{
    public int Name{ get; set; }
    public int AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public BalanceSheet Balance { get; set;}
}
```

And my OData has been configured as below.

```
app.UseMvc(routebuilder =>
{
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

    builder.EntitySet<AccountDetails>("AccountDetails");

    routebuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataCommon", "odata",   builder.GetEdmModel());
});
```

> When i query the API to get the account details, ideally i should be getting 3 properties returned which are - Name, AccountNumber & Balance.
>
> But i get Name and the AccountNumber but not the Balance?

Is that i am doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> My Project has 2 entities

It seems you have only one entity `AccountDetails` and other one `BalanceSheet` is a complex type. You have registered `AccountDetails` entity in Edm Model and complex type registration seems to be missing.

Adding complex type in the Edm model should fix the issue.

```
builder.ComplexType<BalanceSheet>();
```

If it doesn't work, share the controller code and $metadata

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by adding a complexType:

builder.ComplexType();

Additionally I found that different query should be used to get the complex type on UI

Instead of calling http://url/api/AccountDetails?$select=name,accountNumber,balance another url should be used:
http://url/api/AccountDetails?$select=name,accountNumber,balance&$expand=balance

you can only see complex properties via $expand

See details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55476645/2050539