# OData Endpoint missing properties of the Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, odata-v4

I have a class such as this

```
    public class AppData
    {
        [Key]
        [JsonProperty("Id")]
        public Guid AppId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Link")]
        public string Link { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Products")]
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

    }


builder.EntitySet<AppData>("AppData");
```

When I hit this Odata endpoint the Products property is always missing, I can retrieve the AppId and Link no problem.

I can see on similar exmaples on stackoverflow such as this, [OData Endpoint doesn't return all properties of the Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51436527/odata-endpoint-doesnt-return-all-properties-of-the-entity)
However, my Product type is already being used as a EntitySet, changing it to a complex type breaks other API's currently tied to it. Is it possible to have an entityset containing entitysets and return all the data properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi-8/getting-started?tabs=net60%2Cvisual-studio-2022%2Cvisual-studio) here, which showed us to have code below in Program.cs

```
modelBuilder.EntityType<Order>();
modelBuilder.EntitySet<Customer>("Customers");
```

Then I had a test like below. I also tried to set `modelBuilder.EntitySet<Order>("Orders");` and it worked as well.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that was the perfect solution.